# Wrap all the renderDataTable in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a huge R shiny app with many tables of type: renderDataTable.
Occasionally one of them fails because of a data issue, or bug in the code, and that breaks the entire app. I'm trying to find a way to wrap all the renderDataTable used such that if any error happens, an empty datatable is returned.
I have the following code that doesn't work though:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

# define a function that generates a table
generate_table <- function(name) {
  # simulate an error
  stop("An error occurred")
  
  # generate the table (this code will not be executed if an error occurs)
  iris %>% datatable()
}

# define a function that wraps renderDataTable with tryCatch
renderDataTableSafe <- function(expr, ...) {
  tryCatch({
    DT::renderDataTable(expr, ...)
  }, error = function(e) {
    message(paste0("An error occurred with datatable: ", e$message))
    print("Error captured by renderDataTableSafe()")
    return(htmltools::div(class = "empty-table", "No data available"))
  })
}

# define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # add the shinyjs extension
  useShinyjs(),
  
  # output tables
  DTOutput("table1"),
  DTOutput("table2")
)

# define the Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  # render the tables
  output$table1 <- renderDataTableSafe({
    generate_table("dt1")
  })
  output$table2 <- renderDataTableSafe({
    generate_table("dt2")
  })
}

# run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Comment out `stop()` in `generate_table` function and it works.  You need to perform some kind of check to verify if there is an error in your use case and return a NULL table in the `generate_table` function.

Comment: That is basically saying I need to add a tryCatch to every single renderDataTable element and that's what I'm trying to avoid since I have hundreds of them